# Where is the xml file when I use the SharedPreferences in Android Studio? And the Android Studio mobile development does't have data/data folder

Tags: android

this is my code:

```
SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("setting",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
            editor.putString("e-mail",email);
            editor.putString("password",password);
            editor.commit();
```

this is my snapshot of applicaton project file tree:

[image]

Comment: That is created only when you run your app on a device or an emulator. Its never in Android Studio as part of your project.

Comment: they are on your Android device, not in your Android Studio project.

Comment: That is to say, the sharepreference has activity time. when I run this application next time. and the sharepreference data of last time  is destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, there's an option on the bottom right corner of android studio called Device File Explorer. If you have an emulator running or a device connected you can see the data there. You can find the xml for shared preferences under the following path: `data/data/com.your.application.package/shared_prefs`

Note: if you open the file, it won't update dynamically while you're making changes through your app, you have to close it and refresh it before you can see your changes take effect